# Failing to do npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

running npm install in visual code is giving following error.
To fix the error i did the following.

1. From other posts on stack overflow and suggestive errors indicated that i need to install visual code studio with developers tools (python and development with c++).

2.install node-gyp package.

3.added VCINSTALLDIR to env variables

Result: The error is same.

My other teammates are using macOS and they are not facing any issue it's just with windows only.
[Error screenshot from window machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNYQS.png)

Comment: You need VIsual Studio 2015 not VS Code

Comment: i tried with Visual Studio 2022, 2017 and 2015
but nothing worked.

Comment: Try ```loglevel --silly``` like it advices, maybe you'll get more information

Comment: it is the issue with node 16.x.x in windows, ( i faced the similar issue), it solved my issue with NODE 14.x.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested, downgrade your node version to version 14.x.x then it will work. (it worked for me)
For more information .

> https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3670#issuecomment-810986110

You can use multiple versions of node on your machine by using nvm.

> https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html